# Center a div without elements inside

Tags: css

I want center a DIV without having center effect to the elements inside the DIV.

In my case, i have this input (select): [intl-tel-input](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input)

When i do this:

```
<center>
<div id="input">
  <input id="phone" name="phone" type="tel">
</div>
</center>
```

The options of the select centered too, even the container of options changed position.

And here we have an example of the error: http://jsfiddle.net/DtMwr/15/

Thank's to help me to figure it out.

Comment: You said you wanted to center a div, where is your div?  The center tag should not be used.

Comment: Updated the DIV, if center should not be used, what is the replacement ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS to center the form input.  Something like this would work:

**CSS**

```
.center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    padding: 10px;
}

input[name=phone1] { width: 100%; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="center">
  <input type="tel" placeholder="Primary Phone Number" class="input-large" id="p1" name="phone1"/>
</div>
```

That will center the div within its parent, and allow the input to expand to 100% of the parent div's width.  You can adjust the width of the div based on the needs for your layout.

There's some good reading on it here:  http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp

You can see it working in this JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/DtMwr/20/

Also, if you haven't already, you might look into using a framework like bootstrap, foundation, etc.  They've got a good frameworks for implementing a layout that will save you some time.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I already tried with css here: http://jsfiddle.net/DtMwr/16/ but same result. And your example do not center it correctly. any fix ? thank's

Comment: I created a fiddle as part of the answer, you can see it here:  http://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/DtMwr/18/  Ultimately the width you choose is going to be influenced by the rest of your layout.

Comment: But my width are not fixe, dynamically changing :(

Comment: Welcome to web development.  You can expand the input to fill its container.  Here's an example of that:  http://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/DtMwr/20/  The width you choose to center on is going to be based on the rest of your layout.  If you're using a CSS framework, much of the hard work is already going to be done for you.

Comment: Thank's, this helped me to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use center as a tag. Just make it a regular div with an ID.

```
<div id="input_wrapper">
<div id="input">
  <input id="phone" name="phone" type="tel">
</div>
</div>
```

Then, give the outer div a width of 100% and the inner div auto margins with a fixed width.

```
#input_wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}

#input_wrapper #input {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 100px;   
}
```